# Vert.x JavaScript unregisterHandler() and close() not firing BridgeEventType events in Java SockJS handler

Tags: javascript, java, vert.x, sockjs

**Background:** I am using Vert.x Core 3.3.3 and Web 3.3.3 in Java as an *EventBus* server and Vert.x 2.0.0 and SockJS 1.1.1 on a web client in Javascript to connect to the Java *EventBus*. I am connected, able to send and receive messages, and all inbound and outbound traffic is open. Everything is functioning properly.

On the Java side, I am adding a *SockJSHandler* to handle anything routed to "/eventbus/*" so that I can handle events from SockJS connections from JavaScript clients. I am able to capture *BridgeEventType*s such as *BridgeEventType.REGISTER* and *UNREGISTER* and *SOCKET_CLOSED* correctly (except for one instance, hence the question). For example, when a client connects to the *EventBus*, I can see their host and port and the address where they have registered a handler. When I refresh or close a JavaScript client tab in the web browser, I can also see the unregister or closed socket events. This is all working well.

**Issue:** I am trying to manually end the *EventBus* connection or unregister a handler from the JavaScript client. The commands I am using to do this are:

(background: the variable myEB is defined as my vertx *EventBus* connection, *myEB = new vertx.EventBus(link);* and this is working well)

*myEB.unregisterHandler(destination, handler);* and *myEB.close();* are the calls I make.

The *unregisterHandler* and *close* attempts are NOT firing *UNREGISTER* or *SOCKET_CLOSED* events on the Java EventBus's SockJS handler.

**Question:** How do I manually unregister a handler from a JavaScript client or disconnect from the *EventBus* (close the socket connection) such that my *SockJS* handler will fire an *UNREGISTER* or *SOCKET_CLOSED* event?

**EDIT 1:** After some testing, it seems that the *close()* call in the JavaScript client IS firing a *SOCKET_CLOSED* event. The *unregisterHandler()* call is not firing either *UNREGISTER* or *SOCKET_CLOSED* events.

Comment: I guess the best you can do is to provide a reproducer and file a bug report since it looks you're facing a strange behavior.

Comment: @PauloLopes I may have to do that. Not sure if it's a versioning issue or what. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @PauloLopes to follow back up on this question, it looks like the functionality is working correctly for me. I may not have been capturing the event correctly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved. I was not capturing the event correctly. SockJS Handler does fire those bridge events, and they are good candidates for tracking access to the eventbus.